# Can i use eloquent Accessors & Mutators on DB facade ? if no then is there any alternative?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

> For querying the table  I have used DB facade. i want to manipulate the column value before it return result.
>   i used eloquent accessors getAttribute() method in modal but it does nothing

```
    public function findRestaurantByCordinates($request)
    {
        $numPerPage = 6;
        $page = ($request->input('page')) ? $request->input('page') : 1;

            $sql = "r.*,  ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(".$request->input('lat').") ) * cos( radians( res_lat ) ) * cos( radians( res_lon ) - radians(".$request->input('lang').") ) + sin( radians(".$request->input('lat').") ) * sin( radians( res_lat ) ) ) ) AS distance";


            /*custom query for results*/
            $result = DB::table('restaurants as r');

        if($request->input('lat') && $request->input('lang'))
        {
            $result = $result->select(DB::raw($sql));
            $result = $result->having('distance', '<', 20);
        }

        if(!empty($request->input('features')))
        {
            $result = $result->join('res_features', 'r.restaurant_id', '=', 'res_features.restaurant_id');
        }

        if(!empty($request->input('tags')))
        {
            $result = $result->join('res_tags', 'r.restaurant_id', '=', 'res_tags.restaurant_id');
        }

        if(!empty($request->input('features')))
        {
            $result = $result->whereIn('res_features.feature_id', $request->input('features'));
        }

        if(!empty($request->input('tags')))
        {
            $result = $result->whereIn('res_tags.tag_id', $request->input('tags'));
        }

        $result = $result
                    ->groupBy('r.restaurant_id')
                    ->get();

        // Start displaying items from this number;
        $offSet = ($page * $numPerPage) - $numPerPage; // Start displaying items from this number
       //dd($offSet);

        // Get only the items you need using array_slice (only get 10 items since that's what you need)
        $itemsForCurrentPage = array_slice($result, $offSet, $numPerPage, true);

        //dd($itemsForCurrentPage);

        $pagination = new LengthAwarePaginator($itemsForCurrentPage, count($result), $numPerPage, $page, ['path' => $request->url(), 'query' => $request->query()]);


        return $pagination;
    }
```

This method returns json like

```
   [{"restaurant_id":63,"res_title":"Foruche ","res_title_jp":"フォルチェ","city_id":0,"pre_id":22,"res_address":"1-5-2 Dogenzaka Shibuya Tokyo","res_address_jp":"東京都 渋谷区 道玄坂 1-5-2 渋谷SEDEビル　5F","res_lat":"35.6580514","res_lon":"139.6973349","res_overview":"","res_overview_jp":"","res_phone_1":"050-5868-2467 (+81-50-5868-2467) ","res_phone_2":"03-3476-7776 (+81-3-3476-7776) ","res_fax":"","res_email":"","res_website":"","lunch_start_price":0,"lunch_end_price":0,"dinner_start_price":0,"dinner_end_price":0,"occupancy":"","operating_hour":"17:30～翌2:00         15:00～23:00","res_status":"","created_by":0,"updated_by":0,"created_at":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","updated_at":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","slug":"test","distance":6.4750019625656},{"restaurant_id":65,"res_title":"Bishokumaimon ","res_title_jp":"美食 米門 渋谷店","city_id":0,"pre_id":22,"res_address":"Tokyo, Shibuya-ku, Udagawa-cho, 15-1 Shibuya Parco PART1 8F","res_address_jp":"東京都 渋谷区 宇田川町 15-1 渋谷パルコ　PART1 8F","res_lat":"35.6619563","res_lon":"139.6967115","res_overview":"","res_overview_jp":"","res_phone_1":"050-5869-7460 (+81-50-5869-7460)","res_phone_2":"03-4577-6648 (+81-3-4577-6648)","res_fax":"","res_email":"","res_website":"","lunch_start_price":0,"lunch_end_price":0,"dinner_start_price":0,"dinner_end_price":0,"occupancy":"","operating_hour":" 11:00 ～ 15:00        17:30 ～ 23:30","res_status":"","created_by":0,"updated_by":0,"created_at":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","updated_at":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","slug":"test","distance":6.1275693867962},{"restaurant_id":67,"res_title":"GANEZA ","res_title_jp":"ガネーシャ 日本橋浜町店","city_id":907,"pre_id":41,"res_address":"2-30-6 Nihonbashihamacho Chuo Tokyo","res_address_jp":"東京都 中央区 日本橋浜町 2-30-6 花の東京ビル 1F","res_lat":"35.6873505","res_lon":"139.7854157","res_overview":"","res_overview_jp":"","res_phone_1":"","res_phone_2":"+81-3-5623-5460","res_fax":"","res_email":"","res_website":"","lunch_start_price":999,"lunch_end_price":0,"dinner_start_price":1000,"dinner_end_price":1999,"occupancy":"38 seats","operating_hour":"（ランチ）11:00～15:00
    （ディナー）16:00～22:00
    Lunch","res_status":"A","created_by":0,"updated_by":0,"created_at":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","updated_at":"2016-07-03 23:16:19","slug":"test","distance":5.3927689064301},{"restaurant_id":68,"res_title":"Nihonkaishouya ","res_title_jp":"日本海庄や 町屋店","city_id":0,"pre_id":22,"res_address":"6-6-1 Arakawa Arakawa Tokyo","res_address_jp":"東京都 荒川区 荒川 6-6-1","res_lat":"35.7427213","res_lon":"139.777968","res_overview":"","res_overview_jp":"","res_phone_1":"050-5571-0368 (+81-50-5571-0368) ","res_phone_2":"03-5901-4631 (+81-3-5901-4631) ","res_fax":"","res_email":"","res_website":"","lunch_start_price":0,"lunch_end_price":0,"dinner_start_price":0,"dinner_end_price":0,"occupancy":"","operating_hour":"11：30～23：30","res_status":"","created_by":0,"updated_by":0,"created_at":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","updated_at":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","slug":"test","distance":5.5912895038939},{"restaurant_id":77,"res_title":"Jitokkokumiai ","res_title_jp":"じとっこ組合 世田谷経堂店","city_id":0,"pre_id":22,"res_address":"1-25-17 Kyodo Setagaya Tokyo","res_address_jp":"1-25-17 Kyodo Setagaya Tokyo","res_lat":"35.6490287","res_lon":"139.6340795","res_overview":"","res_overview_jp":"","res_phone_1":"050-5868-3517 (+81-50-5868-3517)","res_phone_2":"03-6413-1940 (+81-3-6413-1940)","res_fax":"","res_email":"","res_website":"","lunch_start_price":0,"lunch_end_price":0,"dinner_start_price":0,"dinner_end_price":0,"occupancy":"","operating_hour":"17:00～1:00             17:00～24:00","res_status":"","created_by":0,"updated_by":0,"created_at":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","updated_at":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","slug":"test","distance":11.07793356266},{"restaurant_id":92,"res_title":"Kagoshimakenkirishimashitsukadanoujou ","res_title_jp":"鹿児島県霧島市 塚田農場 中目黒店","city_id":0,"pre_id":22,"res_address":"1-20-5 Kamimeguro Meguro Tokyo","res_address_jp":"東京都 目黒区 上目黒 1-20-5 エーワンビル","res_lat":"35.6446883","res_lon":"139.696901","res_overview":"","res_overview_jp":"","res_phone_1":"050-5570-7183 (+81-50-5570-7183)","res_phone_2":"050-5570-7183 (+81-50-5570-7183)","res_fax":"","res_email":"","res_website":"","lunch_start_price":0,"lunch_end_price":0,"dinner_start_price":0,"dinner_end_price":0,"occupancy":"","operating_hour":"17：00～24：00","res_status":"","created_by":0,"updated_by":0,"created_at":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","updated_at":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","slug":"test","distance":7.8247499035529}]
```

So now what i want is in json result you can see the operating_hour column   which i need to manipulate just want to replace some character like ~ or : in return.

NOTE: The thing is i just wanted to parse those json result using JSON.parse() but it throws some error. I just think  may be its because of those character i was unable to parse it thats why i want to use Accessor but it doesn't help me. You can try to parse that json result. Need Help.

Comment: Please could you show your code for the DB call as well as the code for your model.

Comment: Is the method you have provided in your controller or your model?

Comment: method is in modal 'restaurants' and called from controller.

Comment: In that case can you show the code for your controller method as well???